# starting tomcat failed in Ubuntu (21.20)

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat9

I just installed tomcat on Ubuntu, originally Jenkins were set up to run on port 8080; then after install the tomcat, right before I test run tomcat, noticed it was also using port 8080. then I went ahead and changed the port number for Jenkins some other port number in in Jenkins's config file; and tested Jenkins on the new port -- it worked.

Now,if we come back to the original issue, after reassign some other port number to Jenkins, 8080 should have become available.

when I run the command , don't get any error message; I took it as "no news is good news". As next step, when I ran , I got the following error message

**
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xeu tomcat.service" for details.
**

subsequently, I typed ,

I got the following error:

**
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-02-03 00:52:19 PST; 9s ago
Process: 7341 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
CPU: 2ms

**

can someone help me with this please?

Thank you

Comment: Systemd `status=303/EXEC` typically means that the service script itself is invalid, i. e. it didn't even reached to the point of starting Tomcat. Check this answer for the beginning. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490707/214349

Comment: Thank you! :) it was definitely my side of the problem. This was first time setting up the tomcat, I skipped some step that seemingly "unimportant"

Answer (score 0):

to grant execute access in /opt/tomcat/bin/with:`sudo sh -c 'chmod +x /opt/tomcat/bin/*.sh'`